# Stealing a diamond

Tags: medieval

The scenario is as such :

It is an old dilapidated 3-storey building. No one inhabits the building but currently, the ground floor of the building is used as a temporary place of refuge by a group of thieves, numbering 15 in total. They have recently looted the palace of a noble, getting away with a rather large diamond which has been given by the emperor to the noble for safeguarding.

Our protagonist is tasked with recovering the diamond. In the wee hours of the morning, armed with a stout rope, he manages to reach the top of the building. The thieves are still sleeping so our hero has the chance to do some arrangements. After all, 15 to 1 are odds that he can hardly hope to match.

So what are some of the ways he can single handedly fight the villains and recover the diamond, without a fatal wound ?

Things of importance-

1. It is a medieval setting, so no guns or any other modern devices.
2. Gun powder has not been invented yet but I'm not averse to any other techniques of detonation.
3. He may be armed with other things in addition to the stout rope but the normal weight limits, that any grown man aged 25 can carry, apply.
4. Also, magic and potions are unheard of in this world. So he can't just throw some sleeping powder over them and expect to get away with it.
5. Conflict is inevitable as this would set the stage for an enmity between the leader of the thieves and the hero.

Comment: Is this a realistic setting, or a swashbuckling setting?

Comment: @Schwern: I'm afraid I don't understand your question...

Comment: To whoever gave the down vote, thanks but can you explain why ? I'll make sure that I'm careful not to repeat the error.

Comment: What is the tone of your story? Are you looking for an answer that would work in the real world? Or are you looking for an answer that would work in a movie?

Comment: Your question asks about the actions of a specific character in a specific situation. That isn't about **World**building.

Comment: Allow me to try and explain why your question was closed. WB SE is meant to host questions which will be useful to many other users in the future. Asking for help with setting up your world, explaining a technology, etc. are all on point. Asking about how a character might win a fight when armed with X, Y, Z, and facing A, B, C is ***not***. We can't "write the fight scene" for you as it were, and we can't make up the various details of your building/equipment/enemies such that your hero wins. At that point we're writing the story for you, plain and simple.

Comment: `The thieves are still sleeping` What's wrong with sneaking? Or stabbing all of them while they're asleep?

Comment: take a bottle of alcohol , put some cloth and ignite it , then throw the bottle in the middle of the 15 sleeping thieves. It will explode , they will burn to death. Simply easy and effective.

Answer (score 2):

Bar the doors from the outside and set the house on fire.

The thieves will wake, grab their loot, and try to leave the house by the door. Once they find it barred, they'll try the windows. Since there's 15 of them they'll have to split up to use different windows. In the ensuing panic and chaos our hero can pick out the one with the diamond, take it, and get away.

Comment: That is a very good strategy but won't the amount of fuel needed to set the house on fire be 1. Difficult to carry 2. Strong enough in smell to raise suspicion if it is some oil or petroleum based product...?

Comment: @user96551 Houses, especially medieval ones, are made of and full of things that burn.

Comment: @Schwern, yes full of things that burn, like diamonds

Comment: @Separatrix I was going to say diamonds don't burn... but I'm wrong. [They will ignite as low as 850C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond#Material_properties) which is [the temperature of the average house fire](http://www.aisc.org/DynamicTaxonomyFAQs.aspx?id=1996). Good catch! But I doubt our medieval hero has Wikipedia handy or experience burning gems. Now wouldn't that make an interesting plot twist? "My King, I caught the thieves, but did you know diamonds can burn?" Anyhow, the assumption is the thieves get out of the house with the loot, just in a disorderly fashion.

Comment: You got my upvote just for *Bar the doors from the outside and set the house on fire.* best single like in WB I've seen in a while

Answer (score 1):

Setting the house on fire, as others have suggested, seems a bit unrealistic to me because, unless you have modern fire accelerants, it wouldn't spread quickly enough before they wake up.

Assuming that you have to fight them, as suggested in your question, regardless of any possible alternatives (like setting the house on fire), using the rope to make the thieves stumble and fall is going to be very important.

If you can, remove any weapons they could use before they wake up.

Find some doors you can easily blockade and prepare them in case you are overwhelmed and need to retreat (at least for the moment).

If killing the thieves is ok you can find a part of the building that will easily collapse and try to rig it in such a manner that it will collapse over/under the thieves. This should be done at the beginning of the fight when most thieves will be grouped together to ensure maximum damage.

If the thieves are barefoot or their shoes don't have very resistant soles you can place spikes (nails) on the floor, either equipping yourself with hard shoes or providing a few clear spots you can walk on.

Create bottlenecks.

Use a spear, if possible, to keep the thieves away, drop (throw?) it if the thieves get too close and switch to a sword.